# Multilevel pie by area/% in Adobe Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I’m trying to split up pie slices that I've cut from a circle to have a sort of stacked version similar to what you'd get from stacked bar graph, but each slice is a separate stack.

I can't figure out how to get accurate sizes of the stacks. For example, in the image provided, I’m looking to get a 60%,18%,13%,9% mix of that one slice where the portions in-between each slice represent those percentages. In the first image, I’ve tried to scale the pie slice, and the results I get are very inaccurate (I also thought deducting those percentages from 100 would generate better results, but they didn’t).

The second is a rough estimate of what I’m trying to achieve. What should I do? I could also be making this much harder than it needs to be. If so, please do tell.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @yorik & @scott for the help. What I think we were forgetting is that we need the area of a Donut, after the initial 60% circle.

Heres the process that got me to my answer( would love an easier way if anyone knows please share!):

I needed a pie slice where the portions represented 60%,18%,13% & 9%

Find the area of your outer most circle, A1

A1*0.6=A2

A2 is the 60% circle

For the 18% its a donut so a subtraction needs to be made to get the correct area for it.

18% donut area = D18
D18=0.18*A1

A3 is the circle area we dont know yet and also the outer edge to D18.

A3-A2=D18
A3=D18+A2

Now get the diameter for A3 for the width,

A3=pie*r^2, solve for r then multiply by 2 to get diameter for your circle

Repeat for the 13% circle,

D13=A1*0.13

A4-A3=D13
A4=D13+A3
Solve for diameter of A4

9% donut is the remainder between your outer most circle.

Here are the results:

[image]

and it trimmed down to a pie:
[image]

This correctly shows each portion as a %. Again please if there's an easier method please share.

Answer (score 3):

##### Update:

Total divisions need to equal 100. The previous method left a random 40% which is undesired.

So.... using hard numbers that total 100, which translate to percentages totaling 100.

- I drew a circle with a 120pt diameter (60pt radius x 2).
- Copy, paste in front.
- To figure the next circle multiply the desired offset (18) by 2 (36) add to diameter = 120 + 36 = 156pts. Change the `w` or `h` in the **Control Bar** or **Transform Panel** to 156pts.
- Copy, paste in front.
- Repeat.. 13pt radius x 2 = 26 + 156pts (previous diameter) = 182pts - adjust diameter to 182pts in Control bar or Transform Panel.
- Copy, paste in front
- Repeat 9ptx2= 18 + 182 = 200pts - Adjust diameter.

[image]

This creates circles where the total *radius* equals 100pts, thus 100%.

This will serve as a **guide** for the percentages.

Group, and move it on top of the pie graph and align on center points. Then *scale* the "guide" to match the circumference of the graph.

[image]

*Then* if you split the path you end up with 4 segments of the desired values.

[image]

---

Comment: I've tried this, But maybe I should have clarified, I want the percentages to be reflective of the spaces in between and not back to the center. By doing it like this I end up with 5 separate pieces per slice which would be inaccurate for my purposes.

Comment: @LeeElliott I'm not grasping "Spaces in between". Do you mean the slices between each pie division? Can you just sketch something quickly in Photoshop to kind of reflect what you're after (even if it's inaccurate in terms of numbers). I *think* you *are* going to end up with "pieces". I don't believe the subdivisions can be done on a single object.

Comment: I've added some more context that should be helpful for what im trying to achieve.

Comment: I believe my first image is the same as your second, its just been trimmed already to a pie slice.(91%,87%,82%,40%). But that still leaves me with 5 portions? Am i missing something?

Comment: it is not clear to me, but the scale % for the AI dialog may be for the radius or diameter. In the OP's second image, it definitely looks like the sizes chosen are based on proportion of the radius. The problem here is that if taking e.g. 9% of the radius for one portion and doubling the next chunk for 18%, you are not actually visualizing the percentages because it is an area. I forget the math for this. If it were square, you'd have 1square block vs 4 square blocks or 25/75 rather than 1/2.

Comment: something like: `degrees/360 * (pi)r^2` where `r` is the circle; and then take percentages of that to work out `r` for each portion.

Comment: Answer updated.

Comment: I think you got to the root of the issue for sure @Yorik.

Comment: Thanks @Scott I think you solved the problem! I had a feeling it was math related. Your solution makes sense. If only they had an easier way haha.

Comment: Yeah I miscalculated at first failing to take into account that all values had to total 100%.

Comment: Oh no. I think unfortunately it still may be wrong. Using scripts to double check the area/by area of pie piece for %. im getting 36%,24%,22%,17%. The inner circle should be bigger, and outer layers smaller since they are spread over a wider area. hmm

Comment: Well, there's going to be a marked difference between visual *representation* and *actual* area of coverage. I don't think it's an easy task to calculate the actual area in Illustrator. If you need precise area of coverage, I don't think Illustrator would be the tool to use - at least not to calculate the basic shapes/paths. You would need to calculate the slope of the sides to add to the diameters and then it's *much* more math - which is not really in my wheelhouse at that point.

Answer (score 1):

So given 100 unit radius, you have a formula: `A = 3.14 * r^2`

Which gives a circle with area of 31400 sq units

Take 60% of that you have 18840 sq units. 18% is 5652 sq units, etc.

To convert an area to a radius use: `sqrt(area/3.14)` (sqrt = square root)

To visualize this, you do basically what @scott illustrated:

Starting with the largest fractional area:

- use area to solve for the radius;
- make a circle with that radius;
- add the area of the next smallest circle to the sum of the areas of the previous circles (if using 100 units, the last in the sequence should evaluate to the starting point 31400sq units)
- repeat (goto solve for the radius)